# How to apply keyboard Ins action for JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keylistener

I want to apply Insert action (keyboard has Ins) for JTextPane.when I click on "Ins"(It is presented in keyboard as "Ins") and type some character through keyboard it has replaced the textpane cursor position character with typed character until again "Ins" is pressed.I want to implement this task.Provide some solutions.

Sample code:

```
public class InsertDemo extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JScrollPane scrollPane;
int i=0;
JTextPane textPane;
private static boolean isOvertypeMode;
private Caret defaultCaret;
private Caret overtypeCaret;
public InsertDemo() {
    initComponents();
      textPane=new JTextPane();
      textPane.setCaretColor( Color.red );
      defaultCaret = textPane.getCaret();
      overtypeCaret = new OvertypeCaret();
      overtypeCaret.setBlinkRate( defaultCaret.getBlinkRate() );
      setOvertypeMode( false );
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    tabbedPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    file = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    newFile = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    file.setText("File");

    newFile.setText("NewFile");
    newFile.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            newFileActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    file.add(newFile);

    jMenuBar1.add(file);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void newFileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("");
    i++;
    internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
    internalFrame.setClosable(true);
    internalFrame.setAutoscrolls(true);
    scrollPane=new JScrollPane(textPane);
    internalFrame.add(textPane);
    tabbedPane.add(internalFrame);
    internalFrame.setSize(internalFrame.getMaximumSize());
    internalFrame.pack();
    internalFrame.setVisible(true);
}                                       
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InsertDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InsertDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InsertDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InsertDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new InsertDemo().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenu file;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem newFile;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
// End of variables declaration                   

public boolean isOvertypeMode()
 {
      return isOvertypeMode;
 }
 public void setOvertypeMode(boolean isOvertypeMode)
 {
      this.isOvertypeMode = isOvertypeMode;
      int pos = textPane.getCaretPosition();
      if ( isOvertypeMode() )
      {
           textPane.setCaret( overtypeCaret );
      }
      else
      {
           textPane.setCaret( defaultCaret );
      }
      textPane.setCaretPosition( pos );
 }
 public void replaceSelection(String text)
 {
      if ( isOvertypeMode() )
      {
           int pos = textPane.getCaretPosition();
           if (textPane.getSelectedText() == null
           &&  pos < textPane.getDocument().getLength())
           {
                textPane.moveCaretPosition( pos + 1);
           }
      }
      textPane.replaceSelection(text);
 }
 protected void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
 {
      super.processKeyEvent(e);
       if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED
       &&  e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_INSERT)
       {
           setOvertypeMode( ! isOvertypeMode() );
       }
 }    
class OvertypeCaret extends DefaultCaret {
      public void paint(Graphics g)
      {
           if (isVisible())
           {
                try
                {
                     JTextComponent component = getComponent();
                     TextUI mapper = component.getUI();
                     Rectangle r = mapper.modelToView(component, getDot());
                     g.setColor(component.getCaretColor());
                     int width = g.getFontMetrics().charWidth( 'w' );
                     int y = r.y + r.height - 2;
                     g.drawLine(r.x, y, r.x + width - 2, y);
                }
                catch (BadLocationException e) {}
           }
      }
      protected synchronized void damage(Rectangle r)
      {
           if (r != null)
           {
                JTextComponent component = getComponent();
                x = r.x;
                y = r.y;
                width = component.getFontMetrics( component.getFont() ).charWidth( 'w' );
                height = r.height;
                repaint();
           }
      }
 }
```

}

Comment: [This link should be of some help](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1385467#thread-message-5848960)

Comment: Definitely above link is helped for "Ins" functionality.But,how can I listen the "Ins" key is pressed or not in the keyboard.

Comment: Register a KeyBinding for `java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_INSERT`

Comment: http://java-sl.com/tip_overwrite_mode.html

Comment: Hi,I edit my code with the logic of Insert key.But,It was not working please check it once.

Comment: Anybody can check it once.

Comment: @Guillaume Polet I have edited my code.But,It doesn't work.Please check it once.

Comment: You never set your caret on the textpane. You need a line looking like this: `textpane.setCaret(overtypeCaret);`

Comment: @Guillaume Polet The statement is already available in setOvertypeMode(boolean isOvertypeMode) method belongs to the above program.Please check it once.

Comment: @Guillaume Polet Main problem here is The following methods are not executed isOvertypeMode(), setOvertypeMode(boolean isOvertypeMode),replaceSelection(String text) and processKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) then,How to call these methods.Please run my program then check it once.

Comment: Anybody Please check it my code.I wrote code for "Ins" key but,it doesn't work.Please give me some suggestions where the mistake is happened.

Comment: I don't know what you tried to merge the class provided in my link and your original class. This is of course a complete mess and it will never work. The inheritance used in the linked example is no longer there in your class and therefore, it cannot work that way. Simply copy paste the class and instantiate that one directly. Btw, `setOvertypeMode(boolean isOvertypeMode)` is never called with the value `true`, so your caret is never used.

Comment: @Guillaume Polet  So,How can I merge the provided link with my application.

Comment: Why do you want to merge? Simply copy the code in a new file to create a new class, and instead of having `new JTextPane()` call `new OvertypeTextArea()`.

Comment: One bug in the above process.The Ins is work for currently opened Document not working for previous opened documents.Please check it once.thank you.